# Fail to npm install specific commit of angular library from github

Tags: angular, git, npm

Im using Angular 2.0.0-beta.15 and cant upgrade it, so I had to find a specific commit from github library ([ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd)).

So I found this commit that support 2.0.0-beta.17 which should work for me:

```
"ng2-dnd": "git://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd.git#87a6cc0d395ebc2d14734769a3190836c8af6e1a"
```

but when I go `npm install` I get some error:

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /var/folders/n6/3vqr57k94_z7ynl99yvvtv1r0000gn/T/npm-9640-99198f21/git-cache-fef0b17f/87a6cc0d395ebc2d14734769a3190836c8af6e1a
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0

npm ERR! No version provided in package.json
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

does someone knows how can I get over this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng2-dnd` version 1.5.0

Update your package.json with:

```
"ng2-dnd" : "1.5.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the `No version provided in package.json` problem by upgrading `npm` from version 3.x.x to version to 6.x.x. with `npm install -g npm`.

Looks like the newer versions of `npm` are not so strict on package.json requirements anymore (f.e. specifying a GitHub repo without a version in package.json works with newer npm versions).